# How to get the html generated contents of a php file instead of include the file

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I want to make a cms which generates html pages and creates files to store each page.

Ideally i need something like that:

```
<?php
$file1 = get_produced_html_from('mainPage.php');
/* write the file to a directory*/


$file2 = get_produced_html_from('ProductsPage.php');
/* write the file to a directory*/
?>
```

Is there any function i missed instead of require, include, require_once, include_onse etc?

To clarify: I don't need the php code inside the .php file. I need the html content only which means that the php file should be executed first.

Do you believe the solution is something like using http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php by reading http://domain.com/templates/mainPage.php as a html stream?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: There's [**fwrite**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) or [**file_put_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write content to, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yet to fetch content from a file, yes you can use `file_get_contents` then echo the contents from a variable, or you can use CURL.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong track guys.

Comment: @burzum I guess I might've misterpreted the question then. What did you have in mind for the OP?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I read it as, "How do i get the HTML that, say, `mainPage.php` would generate?"

Comment: @cHao Ah ok, I think I understand now. If I do follow now, wouldn't [**ob_start( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) be an option?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yep.  In fact, it's probably the simplest option, outside of `file_get_contents('http://url/to/page')` (which would require that the site know its address).

Comment: @cHao I understand. I grasped the idea as soon as you gave me a slight nudge earlier ;-) Cheers

Comment: Yes i just want to get the html content from a php file (which will connect to database and get data) and i know the site address. The site address is configurable of course! I am making my thought open to decide which is the best approach, if i am totally wrong, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the output from the buffer.

Here is a piece of code I wrote for somebody to demonstrate a very simple view renderer class.

```
public function render($file) {
    $file = $this->viewPath = APP_ROOT . 'View' . DS . $file . '.php';
    if (is_file($file)) {
        ob_start();
        extract($this->_vars);
        include($file);
        $content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Cant find view file %s!', $file));
    }

    return $content;
}
```

It turns on the output buffer ([ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)) executes the php file and sets the variables and then gets the buffer ([ob_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php)()) and then it cleans the buffer for the next operation ([ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)). You can also use [ob_end_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to directly clean and send the buffer. I would not do that and instead do a proper shutdown process of the app and ensure everything is done and was done right without errors before sending the page to the client.

I think I'm going to make the whole code available on Github soon. I'll update the answer then.

Comment: That's what I thought, after seeing what `cHao` clarified for me.

Comment: I've actually used something like this several times for PHP templates.  Works pretty well as long as the template doesn't modify anything.

Comment: The template should not modify anything except view related data. But you can use the same code and instead doing the include you can use a template engine like Twig where this script is using include().

Answer (score 0):

You can just use cURL to get the whole rendered output from an url.

You can use it like this:

```
// Initiate the curl session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/mypage.php');

// Allow the headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

// Return the output instead of displaying it directly
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the curl session
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the curl session
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The main benefit over `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/mypage.php')` is that it works if `allow_url_fopen` is off.  Well, that, and you could try to send the session cookie to get the URL as the user would see it, if you were feeling particularly brave.  But don't do that.  Or at the very least, close the session in your script before trying it.

Comment: No it just get the html content from another page so no need to impersonate the user. In real life scenario i suggest another layer of interaction of static files with a database via json calls but this is another story!